# Chunk Texture3D GPU generated vertices

Tags: c#, directx, terrain, sharpdx

I read `GPU Gems 3` from NVidia about procedural terrain.
It's quite interesting but not applicable for me because I only read the online version without the shipped DVD so I'm not able to download the source for these samples (I got a shrinked version only). The shaders are split into Vertex, Geometry and Pixel Shader which I can't use because I'm using the `SharpDX Toolkit` and I don't have the possibility to use these shaders.

Now I thought of using the methods of NVidia to implement my own terrain generation - which is created by hand in a `Editor`-View - without random noise etc.
What I want to do is to send my chunks (`List<VertexPositionNormalColor>`) to a shader which creates the triangle list on the gpu without the need of generating it on the cpu.
At the moment I have a list of possible connections (comparable to `Marching Cubes`) which is populated while runtime on the cpu which takes up much memory and time.

The idea what I want to do now is to create a `RenderTarget3D` holding all positions per chunk and generating the triangle list afterward. The generation is based on my own algorithms for vertex generation.
Things you might help me with are:

- How do I generate a `RenderTarget3D` in `SharpDX Toolkit` which stores my `VertexPositionNormalColor` (which will be changed to `VertexPositionColor` after I finished the generation on the gpu) - finished.
- How can I load the positions out of the `RenderTarget3D` to generate the vertices?

  - Can I use the Geometry Shader for this and how?

Some information which might help: `SharpDX Toolkit`; custom terrain (not generated); Chunks are used to separate the positions

If you need anything to help me with this problem tell me what you need.

**Edit #1**:
I managed to get the texture3d generated as I want them to be created but I have a problem with the geometry shader. The code for the geometry shader:

```
[maxvertexcount(36)]
void mainGS(point gsInput input[1], inout TriangleStream<psInput> Stream) {
    float4 position = input[0].position;
        bool anyNot = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < connectionPositionCount; i++) {
        anyNot = anyNot | !hasConnection(position, connectionPositions[i]);
    }

    if (anyNot) {
        for (int i = 0; i < connectionCount; i++) {
            if (
                hasConnection(position, connections[i][0]) &&
                hasConnection(position, connections[i][1]) &&
                hasConnection(position, connections[i][2]) &&
                (connections[i][3] == 13 || !hasConnection(position, connections[i][3]))
                ) {
                    psInput vec1 = (psInput)0;
                    psInput vec2 = (psInput)0;
                    psInput vec3 = (psInput)0;

                    vec1.position = mul(mul(position + connections[i][0], World), View * Projection);
                    vec2.position = mul(mul(position + connections[i][1], World), View * Projection);
                    vec3.position = mul(mul(position + connections[i][2], World), View * Projection);

                    vec1.normal = float3(0, 1, 0);
                    vec2.normal = float3(0, 1, 0);
                    vec3.normal = float3(0, 1, 0);

                    vec1.color = isSet(position + connections[i][0]);
                    vec2.color = isSet(position + connections[i][1]);
                    vec3.color = isSet(position + connections[i][2]);

                    Stream.Append(vec1);
                    Stream.Append(vec2);
                    Stream.Append(vec3);
            }
            Stream.RestartStrip();
        }
    }
}
```

The Tkfxc throws three errors on `Stream.Append(vecX)`: `emitting a system-interpreted value which is not written in every execution path of the shader`.
How can I fix this error in the shader above?

Comment: http://www.geisswerks.com/about_terrain.html here is the source from GPU Gems, also I don't know of any reason why you cannot use SharpDX to implement this algorithm, I did.

Comment: sure, I got it from Geisswerks but I'm not able to read through C/++-Code (because my own code-style is completely different to NVidias). I don't want to `implement` the algorithm but manipulate the algorithm to allow my own terrain (manipulated through editor) to be generated by the GPU instead of on the CPU.

Comment: I managed to get a volume texture working with geometry shader. Now I want to loop through every item in the volume and build the vertices based on some tables. The problem: `emitting a system-interpreted value which is not written in every execution path of the shader l: 139/140/141 r: 26` shrinked source of the shader: [gist.github](https://gist.github.com/AliveDevil/771162c62f6fb2a3b5ef)